# Interpolation with equations

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS:
From a set of points, I would like to interpolate the change on the Z-axis when moving from one point to then next over an area, with a resulting raster of a resolution of 1x1m.
I would then like to use an equation calculate a value between each cell and its surrounding neighbors.

Could anyone briefly explain or nudge me in the direction of a post on a similar matter?

Set of points:
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to interpolate a DEM from gives heigth values?

Comment: Yes, I guess. Like using IDW or any other method would be nice.  A key point is to be able to apply the equations afterwards.

Comment: So, what keeps you from running IDW?

Comment: Nothing, except I never have done it. I guess my question comes back to if it's possible to do this by adding subsequent calculations like I mentioned. 
Because I really don't want to spend time in learning how to IDW in QGIS if I'm not able to do what I ultimately sent out to do.

Comment: IDW is already available in QGIS.

Comment: I know. Alright... Perhaps it's me expressing myself badly.

IDW, yay. I know what it is and I know that it can be done using QGIS.

With the newly produced raster at hand, is it possible to (within QGIS GUI) apply specific equations to calculated values between the cells and their neighboring cells in this raster?

Comment: Can you give an example of an equation you would like to apply?

Comment: It's a single equation - Darcy's law (the rate of the water low in a given direction); dz/dx = k*A*(z_b - z_a)/x, k=soil resistance.

Comment: I would guess you could use [gdal raster calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalrastercalculator), but I dont know...